# Why Morphia is not using @Property value in aggregation?

Tags: java, mongodb, mapping, aggregation-framework, morphia

I'm doing simple test application to explore Morphia capabilities. At the moment I'm trying to make a simple aggregation query on *SaleStatistics* collection.
The query is Filter by product description and grouping by product family and subFamily and sum quantity and amount.
The issue is that while Morphia was doing a correct replacement of property names on the $match phase according to the @Property mappings defined in the classes, it wasn't doing the same replacement in the $group phase. In that case it was using directly the property strings used in the aggregation definition, as you can see in this code snipped from the logging console:

```
2016-06-16 10:09:22 DEBUG AggregationPipelineImpl:36 - stages = [{ "$match" : { "Producto.Denominacion" : "MAGNA"}}, { "$group" : { "_id" : { "productFamily" : "$product.productFamily" , "productSubfamily" : "$product.productSubFamily"} , "saleStatisticsQuantity" : { "$sum" : "$quantity"} , "saleStatisticsAmount" : { "$sum" : "$amount"}}}]
```

Here is my Entity mapping:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity(value="EstadisticaDeVentas", noClassnameStored=true)
public class SaleStatistics extends FactTableEntity {

   @Embedded(value="Gasolinera", concreteClass=GasStationEmbedded.class)
   private GasStationEmbedded gasStation;

   @Embedded(value="Producto", concreteClass=ProductEmbedded.class)
   private ProductEmbedded product;

   @Embedded(value="Cliente", concreteClass=ClientEmbedded.class)
   private ClientEmbedded client;

   @Embedded(value="Turno", concreteClass=ShiftEmbedded.class)
   private ShiftEmbedded shift;

   @Embedded(value="Responsable", concreteClass=ResponsibleEmbedded.class)
   private ResponsibleEmbedded responsible;

   @Embedded(value="Isla", concreteClass=IslandEmbedded.class)
   private IslandEmbedded island;

   @Embedded(value="Vehiculo", concreteClass=VehicleEmbedded.class)
   private VehicleEmbedded vehicle;

   @Property("Origen")
   private OriginType originType;

   @Property("Canal")
   private Channel channel;

   @Property("Cantidad")
   private BigDecimal quantity;

   @Property("Jarreo")
   private BigDecimal samplesQuantity;

   @Property("Precio")
   private BigDecimal price;

   @Property("Monto")
   private BigDecimal amount;

   @Property("CostoDeVenta")
   private BigDecimal costAmount;

   public OriginType getOriginType() {
       return originType;
   }
   public void setOriginType(OriginType originType) {
       this.originType = originType;
   }

   public BigDecimal getQuantity() {
       return quantity;
   }
   public void setQuantity(BigDecimal quantity) {
       this.quantity = quantity;
   }

   public BigDecimal getSamplesQuantity() {
       return samplesQuantity;
   }
   public void setSamplesQuantity(BigDecimal samplesQuantity) {
       this.samplesQuantity = samplesQuantity;
   }

   public BigDecimal getPrice() {
       return price;
   }
   public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
       this.price = price;
   }

   public BigDecimal getAmount() {
       return amount;
   }
   public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
       this.amount = amount;
   }


   public BigDecimal getCostAmount() {
       return costAmount;
   }
   public void setCostAmount(BigDecimal costAmount) {
       this.costAmount = costAmount;
   }

   public Channel getChannel() {
       return channel;
   }
   public void setChannel(Channel channel) {
       this.channel = channel;
   }
   public GasStationEmbedded getGasStation() {
       return gasStation;
   }
   public void setGasStation(GasStationEmbedded gasStation) {
       this.gasStation = gasStation;
   }
   public ProductEmbedded getProduct() {
       return product;
   }
   public void setProduct(ProductEmbedded product) {
       this.product = product;
   }
   public ClientEmbedded getClient() {
       return client;
   }
   public void setClient(ClientEmbedded client) {
       this.client = client;
   }
   public ShiftEmbedded getShift() {
       return shift;
   }
   public void setShift(ShiftEmbedded shift) {
       this.shift = shift;
   }
   public ResponsibleEmbedded getResponsible() {
       return responsible;
   }
   public void setResponsible(ResponsibleEmbedded responsible) {
       this.responsible = responsible;
   }
   public IslandEmbedded getIsland() {
       return island;
   }
   public void setIsland(IslandEmbedded island) {
       this.island = island;
   }
   public VehicleEmbedded getVehicle() {
       return vehicle;
   }
   public void setVehicle(VehicleEmbedded vehicle) {
       this.vehicle = vehicle;
   }


}
```

And here is my Product Entity Mapping:

```
public class Product  {

   @Property("Codigo")
   private Integer code;

   @Property("Denominacion")
   private String description;

   @Property("UnidadDeMedida")
   private String messureUnit;

   @Property("Departamento")
   private String store;

   @Property("Familia")
   private String productFamily;

   @Property("SubFamilia")
   private String productSubFamily;

   @Property("ClaveProveedor")
   private String providerCode;

   public Integer getCode() {
       return code;
   }
   public void setCode(Integer code) {
       this.code = code;
   }

   public String getDescription() {
       return description;
   }
   public void setDescription(String description) {
       this.description = description;
   }

   public String getMessureUnit() {
       return messureUnit;
   }
   public void setMessureUnit(String messureUnit) {
       this.messureUnit = messureUnit;
   }

   public String getStore() {
       return store;
   }
   public void setStore(String store) {
       this.store = store;
   }

   public String getProductFamily() {
       return productFamily;
   }
   public void setProductFamily(String productFamily) {
       this.productFamily = productFamily;
   }  

   public String getProductSubFamily() {
       return productSubFamily;
   }
   public void setProductSubFamily(String productSubFamily) {
       this.productSubFamily = productSubFamily;
   }

   protected String getProviderCode() {
       return providerCode;
   }
   protected void setProviderCode(String providerCode) {
       this.providerCode = providerCode;
   }



}

@Embedded
public class ProductEmbedded extends Product {

}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The shape of the documents can't be guaranteed at that stage and so there's no real Java model to validate against.  It's less than ideal to be sure but we're working on a solution for tracking the document/model change through various pipeline stages.

Comment: But if aggregation was done on SaleStatistics.class and properties grouped are from embedded document I don't see why you can't. This makes combination of mapping and aggregation useless imho

Comment: a $group could happen after a $project, e.g.  and multiple times in a given pipeline.  There's just not way to guarantee the document shape matches any Java type at that point.